# Propositional variables in the definition of satisfaction in a certain logic

Tags: logic

In the logic described in the link [https://www.cs.brandeis.edu/~jamesp/classes/cs216-2009/readings2009/GandS.pdf](https://www.cs.brandeis.edu/%7Ejamesp/classes/cs216-2009/readings2009/GandS.pdf) (p.14) a model $\mathfrak{M} = (D, F)$ consists of a non-empty set $D$ of individuals and an interpretation function $F$. In the case that $\alpha$ is an $n$-place predicate, $F(α) \subseteq D^n$, so that for a propositional variable $P$, $F(P) \subseteq D^0$. $D^0$ is usually defined to be the empty set, so that $F(P) \subseteq \emptyset$, but how is this supposed to account for the possibility that $F(P)$ is assigned either true or false?

I've seen that sometimes $D^0$ is defined to be the diagonal (i.e $D^0 = \{(d,d) \mid d \in D\}$. (I think) this would work, because then $F(P)$ could map either to $\emptyset$ (if false) or to the diagonal otherwise.

It is not clear to me how the truth definition is supposed to work in the case of propositional variables.

Comment: The empty product is not usually defined to be the empty set. The empty product is always defined (except perhaps in some circumstances for $\emptyset^0$) to be a singleton set, for the same reason that $n^{0} = 1$ rather than $n^{0} = 0$.

Comment: $D^0$ is usually defined as the **nonempty** 1-element set whose element is  the empty tuple.

Comment: @Andreas Blass So that $D^0 = \{ ( ) \}$, where $()$ is the empty tuple? And the empty tuple is simply the empty set? But then how would this distinguish the case of $F(P)$ returning true and $F(P)$ returning false?

Comment: $F(P)$ is a function with a 1-element domain; it maps that element, $()$, to "true" or to "false".

Comment: @Andreas Blass The only subsets of $\{ ( ) \}$ are $( )$ (by convention the empty set?) and $\{ ( ) \}$. So could we just as well think of the case $F(P) = ()$ as false and the case $\{ ( ) \}$ as true (like with the von-Neumann coding of true and false)?

Comment: I misread the conventions you quoted. In fact, $F(P)$ is supposed to be a subset of $\{()\}$, so it can be that whole 1-element set $\{()\}$ or it can be the empty set. The former corresponds to the value "true" and the latter to "false".

Comment: And what forces that we take $\{ ( ) \}$ as "true" and $\emptyset$ as "false" and not the other way round? Is it just tradition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$D^0$ is not usually defined to be the empty set. For any reasonable definition, it will have exactly one element. For example it could be the set of all functions from the empty set to $D$. There is exactly one of these: the empty function.

Comment: And how does this account for the fact that a propositional variable may be true or false?

Comment: @Edward.Lin The power set of a one element set has two elements (I see this was covered in the comments some time ago.)